# Как правильно добавить фичу в старые версии

Tags: git

Я хочу добавить изменение в код, которое позволит компилироваться программе на новой платформе. Моя задача сделать это так, чтобы на новой платформе можно было собрать как можно больше версий.

Упрощенно можно представить мой пример так:
[image: Пример]

Я хочу после `defined(ONE)` добавить `|| defined(MYVAR)`
Примерно так: [image: Пример коммита]

Я сначала тупо сделал в конце branch и пытался сделать merge с конкретной версией:

```
git checkout main
git checkout -b newPlatform
git add .
git commit -m "add new platform"
git push
```

А в скрипт сборки добавил:

```
git checkout v3
git merge newPlatform
```

Но это не сработало. Происходил просто merge main и newPlatform.

Далее я попытался добавить своё изменение после C3

```
git checkout C3
git checkout -b newPlatform
git add .
git commit -m "add new Platform"
git push
```

Но при попытке merge с выбранной версией был merge conflict

Потом я попробовал тоже самое, но после C5 и всё заработало, но только для v3 и дальше

Есть ли возможность как-то адекватнее это сделать. Желательно, с большими рамками по версиям.

Comment: Создать и поддерживать три отдельных ветки. Если это не какой-то суровый enterprise, то скорее всего это будет бессмысленная трата усилий

Comment: можно, наверное, нагородить что-нибудь, чтобы все эти дефайны были в отдельном файле, который не имеет никакого общего кода с остальными модулями и используется только для конфигурации, тогда при чекауте в старые коммиты не будет особых конфликтов. Но зачем? Объявить, что платформа такая-то поддерживается с верси v3 и выше и все.

Comment: Спасибо, наверное, действительно лучше будет сделать поддержку только v3+